# New to C, C0000005 and crash error due to long calculation?

Tags: c, crash

I'm trying to use Runge-Kutta 4th order to solve a double pendulum problem. When I try to run the program it crashes and I get a c0000005 error after going through the loop once.
I'm guessing it might have something to do with the long calculation in the System function. Any hints from more experienced C users on what could cause this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
//Attempt to solve double pendulum

//B,a to be used later. m=mass, l=length of rod, initial values for theta's and p's
double B,a,m=1,l=1, g=9.81,theta1i=1,theta2i=1,p1i=0,p2i=0;

static double System(int i,double theta1, double theta2, double p1, double p2);

int main()
{
FILE *f;
f = fopen("Question3.txt", "w");
int i,j;
double N=10000;
double h=1/N;

/*Runge Kutta*/
/*I need 3 sets of parameters k, thus each are defined as arrays of length 3.*/

double k[3][4],x[]={theta1i,theta2i,p1i,p2i}, t=0, T=200;
while(t<T)
{
    printf("%8.3lf\t%8.3lf\t%8.3lf\t%8.3lf\t%8.3lf\n",t, x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]);
    fprintf(f,"%8.31f\t%8.31f\t%8.3lf\t%8.3lf\t%8.3lf\n",t, x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]);

    for (j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if (j==0){k[i][0]=h*System(i,x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]);}
            if (j==1){k[i][1]=h*System(i,x[0]+k[0][0]/2.0,x[1]+k[1][0]/2.0,x[2]+k[2][0]/2.0,x[3]+k[3][0]/2.0);}
            if (j==2){k[i][2]=h*System(i,x[0]+k[0][1]/2.0,x[1]+k[1][1]/2.0,x[2]+k[2][1]/2.0,x[3]+k[3][1]/2.0);}
            if (j==3){k[i][3]=h*System(i,x[0]+k[0][2],x[1]+k[1][2],x[2]+k[2][2],x[3]+k[3][2]);}
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        x[i]=x[i]+(k[i][0]+2.0*k[i][1]+2.0*k[i][2]+k[i][3])/6.0;
    }
    t=t+h;
}
fclose(f);
return(0);
}

double System(int i,double theta1, double theta2, double p1, double p2)
{
if (i==0){return  (p1);}
if (i==1){return  (p2);}
if (i==2){return  ((-0.5*m*l*l)*((6/m*l*l)*(2*p1-3*cos(theta1-theta2)*p2)/(16-9*cos(theta1-theta2)*cos(theta1-theta2))*(6/m*l*l)*(8*p2-3*cos(theta1-theta2)*p1)/(16-9*cos(theta1-theta2)*cos(theta1-theta2))*sin(theta1-theta2)+3*g*sin(theta1)/l));}
if (i==3){return  ((-0.5*m*l*l)*(-(6/m*l*l)*(2*p1-3*cos(theta1-theta2)*p2)/(16-9*cos(theta1-theta2)*cos(theta1-theta2))*(6/m*l*l)*(8*p2-3*cos(theta1-theta2)*p1)/(16-9*cos(theta1-theta2)*cos(theta1-theta2))*sin(theta1-theta2)+g*sin(theta1)/l));}

}
//theta1dt=(6/m*l*l)*(2*p1-3*cos(theta1-theta2)*p2)/(16-9*cos(theta1-theta2)*cos(theta1-theta2))
//theta2dt=(6/m*l*l)*(8*p2-3*cos(theta1-theta2)*p1)/(16-9*cos(theta1-theta2)*cos(theta1-theta2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The choice of the name `System()` is probably not the best; it is too close in name to the standard `system()` function which is quite different. The most likely cause of your trouble is an array subscript out of control somewhere. I've not yet looked hard enough to know where.

Comment: First, googling C0000005 will tell you what causes it. Second, using a debugger will tell you where the crash occurred (and that it's not in System). Third, compile with the warning level set high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has a few issues that stand out, you are accessing `k` out of bounds in a few places, for example:

```
 if (j==1){k[i][1]=h*System(i,x[0]+k[0][0]/2.0,x[1]+k[1][0]/2.0,x[2]+k[2][0]/2.0,
            ^^^
       x[3]+k[3][0]/2.0);}
             ^^^
```

`k` is declared as  `k[3][4]` and so `3` is one outside the bounds of `k` since the indicies start at `0`. As Jonathan points out sicne your loops seems to indicate that you really meant to declare `k` as `k[4][4]` which would fix this problems.

In `System` if `i` is not `0 to 3` then you will fall out of function without a return which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for a value returning function. As Jonathan already mentioned `System` is probably not a good choice as a name since it is very close to the standard `system()` function.

Comment: The problem could be that the declaration should be `k[4][4]`; the nested loops both run [0..4).

Comment: "In System if i is not 0 to 3 then you will fall out of function with a return which is undefined behavior for a value returning function." -- It's obvious that System is never called with a value of i > 3. Still, compiling this with warnings enabled will complain, so it should be fixed. A common way is to use a switch statement and put `default:` before the first case.